# HTML Only - add parameter to current url

Tags: html, parameters

This is my current url

```
www.website.com/accommodation/index.php
```

I want to add `language=chinese` parameter to the end of the current url using just HTML.

I tried `<a href="?language=chinese">chinese</a>` and it just wipes `accommodation/index.php` part of the url and goes to `www.website.com/`. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to just append the parameter using just HTML?

### THE LINK USAGE

This link works as a language switcher. So once someone clicks it, it SHOULDN'T take them to any page. The user should be on the same page with the parameter added to the URL. I am using the parameter value to do few things in the back end using PHP.

Comment: why not `<a href="www.website.com/accommodation/index.php?language=chinese">chinese</a>`

Comment: @zan note that you need the protocol, as well.

Comment: put full url 'www.website.com/accommodation/index.php?language=chinese'

Comment: @zan +1, you can also submit via form method get, just add method = "?language=chinese" and it will add "language=chinese" to current URL

Comment: @EdCottrell first congratulation, protocol ok

Comment: @zan I cant put the absolute url as the url may change. This link is a language switcher. So once someone clicks it, it shouldnt take them to any page. The user should be on the same page, and I am using the parameter value to change few things using php.

Answer (score 1):

location.search += "&language=chinese";

It will automatically add ? if necessary (if not apparent, it will make it ?&language=chinese this way, but that should not matter).